# How to publish vb.net project with other folder

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, publish

In my project I want to include my folder Print when publishing my project.

[image: My folder that I want to add]

When I publish my project it gives me a folder named Application Files then inside of it the folder which content is my exe file.

[image: Published Project]

How can I add my folder Print when I publish my project in Visual studio 2019. Also I'm using vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder to add must appear in your project : simply copy/paste folder to project, and change each file property "copy to output directory" to "copy everyTime".

After that Folder and files will be added to publishing directory.

[image]

[image]

sorry my VS is in french ...